# Controller não executa quando eu volto pro mesmo state

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Olá, estou com um problema no angular e ionic 1
Tenho um aplicativo de market place de restaurantes, semelhante ao ifood, tenho um fluxo de pedido e conforme os passos vão andando eu gravo os dados do pedido em um lugar no localStorage, no final do fluxo(carrinho de compras) eu pego esses dados do localStorage e mostro para o usuário!
O fluxo de pedido no meu app:
Adiciono um produto principal,
Adiciono um Opcional,
Adiciono um Complemento.

Podendo ou não pular uma dessas partes, como por exemplo escolher um opcional e ir direto para o carrinho!

Explicado o meu cenário, o meu problema é o seguinte: quando eu não adiciono um opcional, ao chegar no carrinho o angular não executa o controller do carrinho, e não dá bind nos novos itens que tem no meu localStorage.

Não identifiquei nada de muito diferente nos controllers opcional/complementos e já tentei algumas coisas como limpar cache.

Código dos controllers de complementos e opcionais: http://pastebin.com/7ZMh7rkj

Código das rotas: http://pastebin.com/pWNbVGGv

No template do carrinho eu apenas faço um ng-repeat nos dados que vem do localStorage.

Comment: Por gentileza poste o código relevante; Sem código para analisar fica difícil responder sua pergunta.

Comment: Adicionei alguns códigos relacionados

Comment: Não poste seu código usando links externos; caso esse site saia do ar, sua pergunta não fará sentido. Ao invés disso, poste o fonte relevante  (somente o relevante) diretamente na pergunta